# AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'slugify' when creating slug in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to have my django model automatically create a slug of the model name, but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'slugify'
```

This is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

class school (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=750)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=19, choices=location_choices)
    picture = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="https://i.ibb.co/0MZ5mFt/download.jpg")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=name.slugify(), editable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix - I had to change `name.slugify()` to `slugify(name)`.

Comment: This is not going to work the way you think - [as you've discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941482/making-slug-from-title-and-date-is-giving-me-djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield-djan).

Comment: @solarissmoke Ya... al least I got slugify to work tho...