# Making slug from title and date is giving me 'djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield-djangodbmodelsfieldsdatetimefield'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I made this to make a slug of each blog post, from the title:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify


class post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=75000)
    picture = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="https://i.ibb.co/0MZ5mFt/download.jpg")
    show_date = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=slugify(f"{title} {show_date}"), editable=False)
```

The thing is, this is the slug I get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/blog/djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield-djangodbmodelsfieldsdatetimefield/
```

How can I get it to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/blog/slug-of-title-and-date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're trying to set a default for `slug` is incorrect. `default` must either be a *callable* - i.e., a function - or a static value. When you set it to `slugify(f"{title} {show_date}"` all you're doing is setting a static value, which is the string representation of those field definitions themselves:

```
djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield-djangodbmodelsfieldsdatetimefield
```

It's not going to magically take the value of those fields from the object when it is saved. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55772264/3955830) walks you through the options you have for auto-populating a slug from other fields.

Comment: Do you know what 'Job' is in the 4th option (super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs))?

Comment: That is an error in the example - I have submitted an edit to fix it.